# how to optimise this MYSQL query to run faster

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
requests - request_id, request_message, user_id
responses - response_id, request_id, response_message, user_id, status
```

I am running this query to get the count of unread responses, which belongs to a particular user.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM RESPONSES 
WHERE status = 'U' 
and request_id IN ( SELECT request_id FROM requests WHERE user_id  = '$User_id')
```

Is there any way to optimize it using join??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using an explicit join instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT 
 count(*) 
FROM
  responses res
INNER JOIN
  requests req
ON
  req.request_id=res.request_id
WHERE 
  req.user_id='$User_id'
  and res.status='U';
```

are the request_id fields indexed? I'm guessing it's the PKEY in requests. What about the user_id field in requests?

Also, while I copied your syntax for it, I hope $User_id is not a variable being filled by user generated input. You should be using bind parameters (the method will depend on what language you are using.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!   request_id is PKEY in requests. user_id is PKEY in users, and FKey in requests. $User_id is the user_id of logged-in user. I am using perl.

Answer (score 1):

Joins are better than sub-query
try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM responses r
INNER JOIN requests rrs ON rrs.request_id = r.request_id
WHERE r.status = 'U' 
and r.user_id = '$User_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another query would be this ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM responses
    INNER JOIN requests ON
        (requests.request_id = responses.request_id)
WHERE status = 'U' AND 
      responses.user_id = '$User_id'
```

the max run time for an inner join is max(table_1, table_2),
for nested queries maybe polynomial depending on the query,
so yeah this is faster ...

theres a couple of ways to speed up sql
1) always use fixed row width, ie no string always varchar
2) good indexing. 
3) caching when possible. 
caching could be done on the server (code)... or setting up an auxiliary read-only database.